# Specific position to detect text via Vision Framework

Tags: ios, swift, vision, visionkit

Its possible to specify position on image where to detect text?
I searched everywhere on the net but could not get an answer. I know it's possible detect rectangles, faces, text, and barcodes but my idea is to go to certain (eg x = 50, y = 50) coordinates in the picture and to detect the text there.